# Truffle exec failure

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, javascript

I'm trying to run an external script in truffle.  Basically I deploy the contracts with 'migrate' then want to run this script to set the variables.  I just can't seem to get it to call correctly with:

```
truffle develop
compile
migrate
exec file.js
```

and my code:

```
var Factory = artifacts.require("Factory");

module.exports = async function(callback) {
    var factory = await Factory.deployed();
    console.log(factory.address);
    await factory.setVariables(1000000000000000,1000000000000000,7,1);
}
```

The console logs the correct address, but then it just hangs on the last part.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So it works fine...just not with the truffle develop

So it has to be:

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate
truffle exec file.js
```

Also, no need to put the await on the sendTransaction unless you're running something else right after